# Roboflow dataset blank white

Tags: annotations, dataset, yolo, yolov5, roboflow

I am running YOLO v5 on my customized dataset from roboflow, after I annotated the images on roboflow when I generate a new version of the data set train images are blank white! I did not do any pre-processing or anything.

Comment: Hi, can you try deleting the version(s) you generated with the “white”/blank images, and regenerating a version? We pushed a fix for this today that I believe should solve it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes I tried to delete the version and create a new one it always produces blank white images as well, this dataset is the only one where it happens! I am not sure what is going on, I make no pre-processing or augmentation also.